# java.lang.Exception at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference.createErrorPart(ViewReference.java:115)

Tags: eclipse, testng

After updating the pom file with latest jar file after executing the code from eclipse ide in testng corresponding error is displayed

`java.lang.Exception at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference.createErrorPart(ViewReference.java:115) at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference.createPart(ViewReference.java:101) at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPart(CompatibilityPart.java:304) at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:342) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:58) at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:976) at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:938) at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalInject(InjectorImpl.java:138)`

`
how to sort this issue